# Using Environment Variables in Locales ymls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I use environment variables in the language files in locales folder? I have tried:

```
<%= ENV[..] %>
#{...}
```

but they did not work.

Comment: It is a YAML file, which has a similar structure to a Hash. It is not meant to be interpreted by ruby. Can you explain what you would like to accomplish?\

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file with erb extension, i.e. config/locales/en.yml.erb - not sure if that will work, but worth a try